# Date not coming right in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am storing Event date in following format `2012-07-29` - `YYYY-MM-DD` in ms sql server database  and i am want to show Event Date in following format `MMMM dd, yyyy` but for some reason it keeps coming as  `7/29/2012 12:00:00 AM`

I am using following code

```
protected void getEventDetails()
{
 lblDate.Text = getDate(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EventDate"].ToString());
}


protected string getDate(object dt)
{

    string date = String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", dt);
}
```

I tried to play around but i always keeps me getting the same date for some reason whcih i am not able to understand. Am i doing something wrong.

In database date is stored exactly as `2012-07-29` without any time.

Please advise what is wrong with the code

Comment: you need use `Datetime.Parse` before

Comment: This is something that worked for me. Try this. lblDate.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EventDate"].ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");

Comment: what type for `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EventDate"]`? object? string? Datetime boxed to object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.ToString()` takes in as an argument the formatting.

> A standard or custom date and time format string

Use

```
protected string getDate(string dt)
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dt);
    string date = dateTime.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
}
```

Comment: I had tried `Convert.DateTime(...)` that also gave me same results.. any way your method works

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker you code from sample fail, because you pass _string_ into function, but want format it as _DateTime_

Comment: @Grundy, beat me to it.

Comment: You are right, I was making a stupid mistake passing date as `object dt` while it should have been string.. I just copy pasted code from repeater control function where you actually pass it as object `object dt`.. Got you point.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void getEventDetails()
{
     lblDate.Text = getDate(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EventDate"].ToString());
}


protected string getDate(object dt)
{
   return DateTime.Parse(dt.ToString()).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
}
```

Comment: yeah .. but as we have defined is as a object we need to cast it as a string .

Comment: Please add an explanation to your intention so later some other vistors can follow you way.